# Increase speed of finding minimum element in a 2-D numpy array which has many entries set to np.inf

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, minimum

I have a 16000*16000 matrix and want to find the minimum entry. This matrix is a distance matrix, so it is symmetric about diagonal. In order to get exactly one minimum at each time, I set the lower triangle and the diagonal to `np.inf`. Below is an 5*5 matrix example:

```
inf a0  a1  a2  a3
inf inf a4  a5  a6
inf inf inf a7  a8
inf inf inf inf a9
inf inf inf inf inf
```

I want to find the index of the minimum entry only in the upper triangle. However, when I use `np.argmin()`, it will still go through the whole matrix. Is there any way to "ignore" the lower triangle and increase speed?

I have tried many methods, such as:

1. Use masked array
2. Use `triu_indices()` to extract the upper triangle and then find the minimum
3. Set the entries in the lower triangle and diagonal to `None` instead of `np.inf`, then use `np.nanargmin()` to find the minimum

However, all of the methods I tried are slower the using `np.argmin()` directly.

Thank you for your time, I would appreciate it if you can help me.

***UPDATE 1: Some background of my problem***

In fact, I am implementing a modified version of agglomerative clustering from scratch. The original dataset is 16000*64 (I have 16000 points, each is 64-dimensional). At first, I build 16000 clusters and each contains exactly one point. In each iteration, I find the nearest 2 clusters and merge them, until meet the terminate condition.

To avoid repeated calculation of distances, I store the distances in a 16000*16000 distance matrix. I set the diagonal and lower triangle to `np.inf`. In each iteration, I will find the smallest entry in the distance matrix, and the index of this entry corresponds to the 2 nearest clusters, say `c_i` and `c_j`. Afterwards, in the distance matrix, I fill the 2 rows and 2 columns corresponding to `c_i` and `c_j` to np.inf, which means that these 2 clusters are merged and do not exist anymore. Then I will calculate an array of the distances between the new cluster and all other clusters, then put the array in the 1 row and 1 column corresponding to `c_i`.

Let me make it clear: in the whole process, the size of the distance matrix never change. In each iteration, for the 2 rows and 2 columns correspond to the 2 nearest clusters I found, I fill 1 row and 1 column with `np.inf` and put the distance array of the new cluster in the other 1 row and 1 column.

Now the bottleneck of the performance is finding the smallest entry in the distance matrix, which takes 0.008s. The run time of the whole algorithm is about 40 minutes.

***UPDATE 2: How I compute distance matrix***

Below is the code I used to generate distance matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

dis_matrix = pairwise_distances(dataset)

for i in range(num_dim):
    for j in range(num_dim):
        if i >= j or (cluster_list[i].contain_reference_point and cluster_list[j].contain_reference_point):
            dis_matrix[i][j] = np.inf
```

Nevertheless, I need to say that generating the distance matrix is not the bottleneck in the algorithm now, because I generate it only once, and then I just update the distance matrix (as mentioned above).

Comment: How are you creating the distance matrix?  If it's symmetric it's likely self-referential right?  Can you use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) instead of however you're making it now?  That only outputs (and only calculates) the upper triangle.  Then you can use the result of `argmin` against `triu_indices`, or find some way to calculate it directly (since all those indices will be huge).

Comment: Show how you compute the distance. I think I can help you a lot by rewriting that step entirely

Answer (score 4):

If we back up a step, assuming the distance matrix is symmetric and based on an `(i, n)` shaped array with `i` points in `n` dimensions, and the distance metric is cartesian, this can be done very efficiently with a `KDTree` data structure:

```
i = 16000
n = 3
points = np.random.rand(i, n) * 100

from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
tree = cKDTree(points)
close = tree.sparse_distance_matrix(tree, 
                                    max_distance = 1, #can tune for your application
                                    output_type  = "coo_matrix") 
close.eliminate_zeros()
ix = close.data.argmin()
i, j = (close.row[ix], close.col[ix])
```

This is pretty blazing fast, but it depends on your application and distance metric if it's useful for you.

If you don't need the distance matrix at all (and only need indices), you can do:

```
d, ix = tree.query(points, 2)
j, i = ix[d[:, 1].argmin()]
```

EDIT: this doesn't work well for high-dimensionality data.  Since you're up against the curse of dimensionality, you'll probably need to brute force.  I recommend `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` for this:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
D = pdist(points, metric = 'seuclidean')  # this only returns the upper diagonal
ix = np.argmin(D)

def ix_to_ij(ix, n):
    sorter = np.arange(n-1)[::-1].cumsum()
    j = np.searchsorted(sorter, ix)
    i = ix - sorter[j]
    return i, j

ix_to_ij(ix, 16000)
```

Not completely tested but I think that should work.

Comment: Hi there, firstly thanks a lot for your time! The whole algorithm still needs 40 minutes to finish. I just added some background of my problem, could you please spare some time and take a look? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ahh, yeah.  For KDTree to be efficient you need `i >  2**n` .  With 64 dimensions you're stuck brute forcing.  Is it possible to PCA your data to reduce dimensionality before clustering?

Comment: I will try PCA and check whether there is a decrease in accuracy. I hope the accuracy does not change a lot....

Answer (score 2):

One thing I can think of that *might* give you a boost is using `numba.njit`:

```
@njit
def upper_min(m):
    x = np.inf
    for r in range(0, m.shape[0] - 1):
        for c in range(r + 1, m.shape[1] + 1):
            if x < m[r, c]:
                x = m[r, c]
```

Be sure not to time it the first time you run it. The compilation is slow.

Another way could be to use sparse matrices somehow.

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your time! I tried `numba` and it gives me a 28% increase in speed.  However, the whole algorithm still needs 40 minutes to finish. I just added some background of my problem, could you please spare some time and take a look? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Instead of range, you could even use prange to enable multithreading.

Comment: I have updated the method I used to calculate the distance matrix

Answer (score -1):

You can select upper triangle of array by masking, simple example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
# Mask of upper triangle
mask = np.array([[True, True],[False, True]])
# Masking returns only upper triangle as 1D array
min_val = np.min(arr[mask]) # Equal to np.min([0, 1, 3])
```

So instead of making lower triangle as `inf`, you have to generate a mask where lower triangle is `False` and upper triangle is `True` and apply masking `arr[mask]` which returns 1D array of upper triangle, then you apply min

Comment: triu_indices does this more efficiently and yet it's slower